# Error torsocks: Unable to resolve

Tags: linux

I'm using `torify` on `CentOS`, and when I try `torify wget ...` I always get the same error message:

```
ERROR torsocks[32190]: Unable to resolve. Status reply: 4 (in socks5_recv_resolve_reply() at socks5.c:666)
failed: Non-recoverable failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address “www.baidu.com”
```

Can anyone help me on that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does tor work otherwise, and is there anything reported in your tor logs?

Comment: Use cURL with socks name resolution : torsocks is VERY glitchy

Comment: `wget` also respects the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin are you suggesting `curl` with option  `--socks5 <host[:port]>` or `--socks5-hostname <host[:port]>` ??

Comment: @Rho Phi yes, the exact mechanism you've mentioned. It can be used either by the command line switches you've sent, or by specifying proxy address as ’socks5h://’ for a newer versions of cURL